# How do we know what angle formula X1 is encoded into qml.MottonenStatePreparation?

Tags: mathematics, pennylane

Known that X1 is a quantum state, it is prepared by qml.MottonenStatePreparation. How do we know what angle formula X1 is encoded into qml.MottonenStatePreparation? can be interpreted in python code. Here is Refs: https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_variational_classifier.html